# SQL-Pivot de una tabla temporal

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Tengo esta tabla temporal con estos registros:

```
SELECT Columna,Rango,Cantidad FROM #Columnas
```

[image: Registros de la tambla Temporal]

¿Cómo podría hacerlo con *PIVOT* para que tenga como FILA las columnas de "Columna" y "Cantidad" para que logre quedarme así?

```
Columna ID -> 1    2  3    4 5  6    7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
Cantidad   -> NULL 1  NULL 2 2  NULL 4 1 2 2  1  2  1  1
```

Comment: ¿Conces de antemano los posibles números que hay en la columna `columna`?

Comment: La columna **columna** es un **Int Identity** del 1 hasta el 31

Comment: Podria ser que sea mas de 31 o 31 es lo maximo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias probar con esto.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Cantidad ,Columna FROM #Columnas) P
PIVOT  
(  
SUM (Cantidad)  
FOR Columna IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])) AS pvt
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación!

Answer (score 1):

Hacer un pivote sobre una tabla temporal no es distinto de hacerlo sobre cualquier otra tabla.

Utiliza tu tabla temporal en el `select` inicial y luego *pivotea* por los valores de la `columna`.

En código, se vería algo así (he resumido las columnas, es solo para que te hagas una idea):

```
select *
  from (select   Columna
               , Cantidad 
          from #Columnas
       ) as t
 pivot (    sum(cantidad)
        for columna in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[31])
       ) as p
```

Lo que produce un resultado como este:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      31
------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
8       1       1       1       NULL    3       9       1       3       4       NULL

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Gracias por la info!